# Searching in Different Drupal websites

Tags: apache, drupal, solr

I have 4 drupal websites different in Database and Files. 
I need to use drupal search for any website to get any content related in all others. 
Also, In article content type need to get related articles through all website.

Is Apache solar is best solution for that? and what's its limitation for this task?

Thanks

Comment: Sphinx search engine may produce a single index from your 4 db. Unfortunatly https://www.drupal.org/project/sphinx for Drupal 7 is mot ready yet. So you should embed sphinx result in D7 yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read this

http://www.phase2technology.com/blog/exposing-external-content-to-drupals-search/

Do go through the comments as well.

It would be better to treat all 4 sites as different/external in case their DB's are different.